# Kettle running on windows with commands

Tags: kettle

i use Kettle running on windows system with commands
my code:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>F:\data-integration\pan.bat /file F:\data-integration/repository/test/test.ktr /param:test=pp
```

when i add `/param:test=pp` 
there has a problem:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/F:/data-integration/launcher/../lib/slf4j-log
4j12-1.7.7.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/F:/data-integration/plugins/pentaho-big-data-
plugin/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.7.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.

SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
2019/04/28 17:44:11 - Pan - ERROR (version 8.3.0.0-211, build 8.3.0.0-211 from 2
019-03-12 03.40.41 by Administrator) : Command Line Options
```

I have set the test parameter in test.ktr,but also can't run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, i use this template for the Batch files

C:

cd\Pentaho\design-tools\data-integration\

Pan.bat -file:C:/foo/bar/your.ktr "-param:test=pp"

I usually wrap the param:[name]=[value] clauses in quotes, because in PDI Windows, you're working with a multiple platform system, you're running a Windows command that's going to land on a Unix VM (The Java VM), so slashes, forward slashes and other control characters have to be ommited.

The only command that i don't wrap around quotes is the -file.

If you're using a the command straight from CMD, remenber you need to navigate to your data-integration folder in order to call Pan / Kitchen with the commands.